# loading sound files from urls in openFrameworks

Tags: url, audio, openframeworks

I'm having a problem trying to load sound files via URLs in openFrameworks. I'm trying to load this specific sound:

```
http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/240/240256_1772721-hq.mp3
```

and i'm coding it in `setup()` like so:

```
sound.loadSound("http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/235/235801_1272172-hq.mp3", true)
```

and sending a call to `play()` the sound when the mouse is clicked, however, I am getting no sound at all.

To further investigate I ran an if statement to see if the file is loading at all, and it isn't. My question is, is it possible to load sounds directly from a **URL** or would I have to work around by attempting to download the sound and play it back once it has downloaded?

I'm new to the site so please let me know if any additional information/code is needed to make the understanding of my question easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a sound directly from the web using `loadSound()`. You need to first download it in the `bin/data` directory of your project and then call `loadSound()`.

To retrieve the file you can use `ofSaveURLTo`. See the [documentation](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/utils/ofURLFileLoader.html#show_ofSaveURLTo) for more information.